# Storing an array of JSON Objects in a couchDB field value

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, couchdb

I'm trying to store an array of JSON objects like this as a single field value in a couchdb document (I have reformatted this field value with JSONLint for readability)

```
[
   {
       "identifier": "2208879208",
       "name": "Some name",
       "description": [
           "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
       ],
       "attractions": [
           {
               "identifier": "1910",
               "summaryTitle": "Some title"
           },
           {
               "identifier": "1270",
               "summaryTitle": "Another title"
           }
       ]
   },
   {
       "identifier": "2208879208",
       "name": "Some name",
       "description": [
           "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
       ],
       "attractions": [
           {
               "identifier": "1910",
               "summaryTitle": "Some title"
           },
           {
               "identifier": "1270",
               "summaryTitle": "Another title"
           }
       ]
}
```

]

The original data is from a Solr query, which I then send to couchDB with Mickael Bailly's CodeIgniter couchdb library, on PHP 5.3, and apache 2.2.22, couchDB 1.3.0 on Windows 8  WAMPserver

It's valid JSON according to JSONLint, and I can create the document fine, but when I view the document in Futon, couchdb seems to have treated it like a string rather than an array of objects, and I'm unable to click the + signs in Futon to expand / contract the nodes within the saved field UNTIL I double click the field value to edit the source, and add a space between the first 2 chars [ { and then click the tick again.

It then displays in a clickable tree view, and I can read the doc field out again as JSON.

So I guess my question is - What am I missing when I create my couch document? Do I need to format the field data differently?

CouchDB seems to treat this field just as a string value when I create the document, which I find odd. I've tried adding the space in manually before I send the data to couch but I get the same result.

I've also tried using cURL manually to create the document (outside of the couchdb library) but I get exactly the same result and I'm stumped. Any tricks or tips would be much appreciated! I can't find anyone with a similar issue so I'm thinking I must have a basic misunderstanding here :s

```
$payload = json_encode($data_a);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/dbname/'.$uid);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json','Accept: */*'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:pass');

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: what is the curl command you are using?

Comment: added current attempt above as couldn't get formatting right in this comment box :S

Comment: it really depends on what is in `$data_a`

Comment: I finally found out what the issue was - it was completely unrelated to curl, or couch. I was accidentally json_encode()-ing the data twice! Thanks for your time - I can now get back on with what I was doing! I hate my job sometimes :)